# Successful test from OpenScript fails in Test Managger with "Find Object Timeout" error (Oracle)

Tags: oracle, testing, timeout, automated-tests, openscript

I am trying to execute in  Oracle's Test Manager, an automatic test which I created in Oracle's OpenScript.

My script in OpenScript is executed successfully as you can see below:

[image: OpenScript test execution]

---

When I execute the same test in Test Manager, I get a `Find Object timeout` . You can see below the error:

[image: Test Manager test execution]

---

Because of this eror, I have added the following event in my OpenScript test case and tried to execute it again from Test Manager. The error persists; the only change is that the time before the timeout increased to 300.

```
        web.image(
            99,
            "/web:window[@index='0' or @title='Checkout | Test Store']/web:document[@index='0']/web:img[@index='4' or @src='http://duckshop.scl.intra/duckshop/cache/6e12ca9108aae3731f906138977ccac52f2a38b5320x320_fwb.png']")
            .waitFor(300);
    {
        think(3.056);
    }
```

---

Why do I get this error?

---

> UPDATE: As I have discovered only the first time the test is passed. I
>   tried to use command line option while executing the test such as that
>   no cookies will be stored or cache, but still I can't solve my
>   problem.

Answer (score 0):

when we execute script from OTM(Oracle Test Manager). WaitFor() and Think() most cases will not work in server level.

Alternative use

```
WaitForPageLoaded()
wait(5)
delay()
web.image("/web:window[@index='0' or @title='Checkout | Test Store']/web:document[@index='0']/web:img[@index='4']")
        .waitForPageLoaded();
```